# Spliting string with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string like this -

```
query = "UserId:(\"787D01FE-D108-4C83-A2E2-4B1DA3166A5C\" OR \"CCA47A4F-B4FA-405C-B34E-EC2E0B1F374C\") AND CreatedDate:[2017-06-20T06:14:11Z TO 2017-07-20T06:14:11Z] OR FirstName: Abc ";
```

But I want to get the result in array like this -

```
queries=
{
   [0] UserId:(\"787D01FE-D108-4C83-A2E2-4B1DA3166A5C\" OR \"CCA47A4F-B4FA-405C-B34E-EC2E0B1F374C\")
   [1] AND
   [2] CreatedDate:[2017-06-20T06:14:11Z TO 2017-07-20T06:14:11Z]
   [3] OR
   [4] FirstName: Abc 
}
```

**Updates:**

So far I had used this  -

```
        var result =
                    (from Match m in Regex.Matches(query , @"\[[^]]*]|\{[^}]*}|[^:]+")
                         select m.Value)
                        .ToArray();
```

But ended with this -

[image]

**SOLUTION:**

Based on the solution suggested by @NetMage I added some more variations to take care of double quotes, conditions inside parenthesis [Here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cw%2b%3f%5cs*%3a%5cs*%28%5c%28.%2b%3f%5c%29%7c%5c%22.%2b%3f%5c%22%7c%5c%5b.%2b%3f%5c%5d%7c%5cw%2b%29%29%7c%28%3f%3a%5c%28%5cw%2b%3f%5cs*%3a%5cs*%28%5c%28.%2b%3f%5c%29%7c%5c%22.*%3f%5c%22*%7c%5c%5b.%2b%3f%5c%5d%7c%5cw%2b%29%5c%29%29%7c%28%5bA-Z%5d%2b%28+%5bA-Z%5d%2b+%29%3f%29&i=UserId++%3a+%28%22787D01FE-D108-4C83-A2E2-4B1DA3166A5C%22+OR+%22CCA47A4F-B4FA-405C-B34E-EC2E0B1F374C%22%29+AND+CreatedDate+%3a+%5b+2017-06-20T06%3a14%3a11Z+TO+2017-07-20T06%3a14%3a11Z+%5d+AND+%28FirstName++%3a+++%22Abc%22+OR+LastName++%3a+++%22Xyz%22%29)

```
UserId  : ("787D01FE-D108-4C83-A2E2-4B1DA3166A5C" OR "CCA47A4F-B4FA-405C-B34E-EC2E0B1F374C") AND CreatedDate : [ 2017-06-20T06:14:11Z TO 2017-07-20T06:14:11Z ] AND (FirstName  :   "Abc" OR LastName  :   "Xyz")
```

Regex Expression -

```
(?:\w+?\s*:\s*(\(.+?\)|\".+?\"|\[.+?\]|\w+))|(?:\(\w+?\s*:\s*(\(.+?\)|\".*?\"*|\[.+?\]|\w+)\))|([A-Z]+( [A-Z]+ )?)
```

Comment: take a look at string.Split: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I had gone through this but couldn't found any solutions. Better to suggest an answer

Comment: What had you tried?   Better to fix your non-working code than supply something you've already tried.

Comment: I had updated my answer with what I had tried

Comment: So you haven't tried ``string.Split``?

Comment: I did but all the time I am getting some different results. problem is that User may/may not pass spaces before and after colon or may pass "AND" or "OR" or "NOT" and inside parenthesis or out of parenthesis. What I want is to split "fieldname:condition1", "operator", "fieldname:condition2"

Comment: Stop trying to use regular expressions to parse a non-regular language. **Write a lexer and a parser**.  It's not hard, and it builds character!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this work for you?

```
var pattern = @"(?:\w+? ?: ?(\(.+?\)|\[.+?\]|\w+))|([A-Z]+( [A-Z]+ )?)";

var ans = Regex.Matches(query, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: Great Solution! I add some more variations to it - (?:\w+?\s*:\s*(\(.+?\)|\".+?\"|\[.+?\]|\w+))|([A-Z]+( [A-Z]+ )?)|(?:\(\w+?\s*:\s*(\(.+?\)|\".+?\"|\[.+?\]|\w+)\))